# Pythonbrew cant install python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.3, pythonbrew

I have installed multiple python versions using "pythonbrew install ". However, For python 3.3, I get the message :

```
ERROR: Unknown python version: `Python-3.3`
```

Is there a different sub version i need to specify? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify another version number after the .3.

It should be something like:

pythonbrew install 3.3.1 (which is the latest available version).

See if that works.